# How to discover network usage of android applications while connected to a network

Tags: android, android-networking

how to monitor the network states and applications usage of this network using android API, how to determine the speed, usage (Mb, Kb...), connection level (good, bad, average), just as junior developer need to know what classes to use and where could I find references to achieve this.

Answer (score 2):

The following links should help you figure out how to programatically detemrine the data usage per application.

https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Bandwidth/TrafficMonitor

http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/app-builder/create-a-network-monitor-using-androids-trafficstats-class/774

http://agolovatyuk.blogspot.com/2012/04/android-traffic-statistics-inside.html

To find Network Statistics you can use and track the number of bytes sent/received per UID (application).-

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/TrafficStats.html